# Layer selection mutually exclusive using Mapbox GL JS

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox-gl-js

I'm new to using mapbox gl js and a beginner web developer. I have three layers being rendered on my map. I'm using the mapbox gl js example (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/) to toggle between layers, however the example created a nav element that doesn't work the way I'd like it to.

Right now, the nav element allows all the layers to be active and selected at once. I would like the nav element or a button to allow only one layer selection at a time. The element now forces the user to click through several times to make a layer visible. This isn't user friendly.

I essentially am looking for the L.control.layers function leafletjs uses. I cannot find a clean equivalent for mapbox gl js.

```
 var toggleableLayerIds = [ 'Total Votes Cast', 'Percentage of Vote for Tiffany Caban', 'Percentage of Vote for Melinda Katz' ];

  for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
  var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];

  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = '#';
  link.className = 'active';
  link.textContent = id;

  link.onclick = function (e) {
  var clickedLayer = this.textContent;
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility');

  if (visibility === 'visible') {
  map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'none');
  this.className = '';
  } else {
  this.className = 'active';
  map.setLayoutProperty(clickedLayer, 'visibility', 'visible');
  }
  };

  var layers = document.getElementById('layerToggle');
  layers.appendChild(link);
  }
```

Based on feedback, I want to change my approach and instead use a radio input to change through layers. I create a function called baselayerchange that should do this, but when I apply this function to the onclick event listener on the radio button an error logs that baselayerchange is not a valid function.

```
<form action="" id="layerToggle">
    <input type="radio" name="layer" value="Total Votes Cast" onclick="baselayerchange ()"> Total Votes Cast<br>
    <input type="radio" name="layer" value="Percentage of Vote for Tiffany Caban" onclick="baselayerchange ()"> Tiffany Caban Vote %<br>
    <input type="radio" name="layer" value="Percentage of Vote for Melinda Katz" onclick="baselayerchange ()"> Melinda Katz Vote %
  </form>

 function baselayerchange () {
    if (layerToggle.value === 'Total Votes Cast') {
        $("totalVoteLayer").show();
        $("tiffanyLayer").hide();
        $("melindaLayer").hide();
    } else if (layerToggle.value === 'Percentage of Vote for Tiffany Caban') {
        $("tiffanyLayer").show();
        $("totalVoteLayer").hide();
        $("melindaLayer").hide();
    } else if (layerToggle.value === 'Percentage of Vote for Tiffany Caban') {
        $("melindaLayer").show();
        $("totalVoteLayer").hide();
        $("melindaLayer").hide();
    }
  };
```

The various layers are added to the map using the .addLayer method and then assigning it to a new variable. Ex:

```
  var totalVoteLayer = map.addLayer({
    'id': 'Total Votes Cast',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': sourceUrl,
      },
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': {
        'property': 'Refactored_Total_Votes_ED',
        'stops': [
          [0,  '#FFFFFF'],
          [1,  '#fee5d9'],
          [30, '#fcbba1'],
          [50, '#fc9272'],
          [70, '#fb6a4a'],
          [100, '#de2d26'],
          [125, '#a50f15'],
        ]
      }
    },
  });
```

Comment: L.control.layers only provides radio-button selection for base layers - it would do the same as you're seeing here for overlay layers. However - it looks like the mapbox gl example you're using codes the layer switching itself rather than relying on a library control, so you can add mutual-exclusivity in your own code.